# How do I create counter variable inside 2d array loop?

Tags: ruby

so I have an `Array`

```
arr = [[2,3], [4,7] [2,9]]
```

and want to keep counter inside my loop

```
for x, y in arr do
  counter = 0
  counter += 1
  p counter
end
```

it prints 1 because i initialized counter with 0 and it keeps doing that. Is there any way to somehow keep track of how many times my loop has run for? I don't want to create temporary variable OUTSIDE loop

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
arr.each_with_index do |(x, y), i| 
 # you have your x, your y and the index in i
end
```

Comment: If you want a 1-based counter, there's `each.with_index(1)` (note the `.`, those are two methods)

Comment: I think a comment is enough, but feel free to add it if you like :-)